Python normalize a hierarchical tree into pandas dataframe
I have the following dataframe which holds a tree-like structure. The hierarchy levels range from 2 to 4:
df = 
    Hierarchy ID  Value
0   1.0           T1
1   1.1           T2
2   1.1.1         T3 
3   1.1.2         T4
4   1.2           T5
5   1.2.1         T6
6   2.0           T7
7   2.1           T8
8   2.1.1         T9
9   2.1.1.1       T10
10  2.1.2         T11
...

I want to normalize this into a filterable pandas dataframe such as the following. The "N.0" level should always be the main level 1 and the rest should follow it.
df = 
    Level_1   Level_2  Level_3  Level_4
    T1        T2       T3       Nan
    T1        T2       T4       Nan
    T1        T5       T6       Nan
    T7        T8       T9       T10
    T7        T8       T11      Nan
...

I don't know how to resolve this, any help?

This seems to do the trick – getting from your dataframe to the mapping dict, and from the output print()ed back to a dataframe is left as a separate exercise.
This assumes all "paths" exist in the mapping.
mapping = {
    "1.0": "T1",
    "1.1": "T2",
    "1.1.1": "T3",
    "1.1.2": "T4",
    "1.2": "T5",
    "1.2.1": "T6",
    "2.0": "T7",
    "2.1": "T8",
    "2.1.1": "T9",
    "2.1.1.1": "T10",
    "2.1.2": "T11",
}


def key_to_tuple(key):
    bits = [int(p) for p in key.split(".")]
    while bits[-1] == 0:
        bits.pop()
    return tuple(bits)


mapping = {key_to_tuple(key): value for key, value in mapping.items()}

for key, value in mapping.items():
    # Figure out if this is a leaf node
    if not any(k for k in mapping if k[: len(key)] == key and k != key):
        # Map back to the original key
        path = [mapping.get(key[: x + 1]) for x in range(len(key))]
        print(path)

prints out
['T1', 'T2', 'T3']
['T1', 'T2', 'T4']
['T1', 'T5', 'T6']
['T7', 'T8', 'T9', 'T10']
['T7', 'T8', 'T11']


The original question wanted a data frame.  Appending each path to a list, then pass it to pd.DataFrame should do it.

Since this is a graph problem, you could use networkx to compute the graph and then find all root->leaf paths:
import networkx as nx

# create a ID -> Value mapping
mapper = dict(zip(df['Hierarchy ID'].str.removesuffix('.0'),
                  df['Value']))

# create the graph
G = nx.from_edgelist(((mapper.get(i.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0]),
                       mapper.get(i))
                      for i in mapper.keys()),
                     create_using=nx.DiGraph)
G.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(G))

# for each subgraph
# for each root
# find all paths
out = []
for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    H = G.subgraph(c)
    for root in (v for v, d in H.in_degree() if d == 0):
        leaves = [v for v, d in H.out_degree() if d == 0]
        out.extend(list(nx.all_simple_paths(H, root, leaves)))   
    
# convert to DataFrame
out = pd.DataFrame(out)

Output:
    0   1    2     3
0  T1  T2   T3  None
1  T1  T2   T4  None
2  T1  T5   T6  None
3  T7  T8   T9   T10
4  T7  T8  T11  None

Graph:

Graph without mapping the values:

